# SQL Server Agent Job is finished successfully but not executing (.appref-ms) files from an SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent

I am trying to execute a few executable files (.appref-ms) once a day. These files are essentially console applications that I created in C#.

I created an SSIS package that run all of the files at the same time.

In Visual Studio when I execute the package, it works fine. Also, when deploying the package to Integration Services Catalog in SQL Server and expending the package to execute the (.dtsx) file, also works fine.

Now, I want to automate the process and for that, I created a SQL Server Agent job.

The job has one step.

[image]

When I execute the job, it completed successfully but the executable files (.appref-ms) never ran.

I tried running the job under a proxy account but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you execute that package manually? Does it work then?

Comment: @SlavaMurygin The package yes. When I expand the package and click execute the .dtsx file. The executable files (.appref-ms) are opening and it works fine. Not through the job tho.

Comment: executable files (.appref-ms) never ran, what it means? Did this job step run without error or when SQL job executed may skip this step? check all executions under Integration services catelogs

Comment: Does job runs the package then? How do you know?

Comment: @CR241, it means that the console applications did not open but the job finished successfully. I checked all executions and I do not see any errors.

Comment: @SlavaMurygin as you see in the screenshot above, the only step in the job runs the package.

Comment: I mean do you have any logging within DTS package, which would tell you about the execution. Or logging in SSIS?

Comment: @SlavaMurygin yes I do. No errors whatsoever. I see validatiod started. Validation complete, Finished time Elapsed time. in this order.

Comment: So I just re-created the job then I added the following principals NY AUTHORITHY\SYSTEM and NT Service\MSSQLSERVER to the proxy account and in the window above where it says Run As: i selected the proxy account. It is working now. Thank you @SlavaMurygin